# How to create a Json object in Asp.net mvc 3 controller?

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3

1. How would you create this Json object from my ASP.Net MVC 3 Controller ?
2. Newbie in Json, in this Json object notation, can I replace the `[` and `]` sign with `{` and `}`?

   ```
   var data = [
       {
           label: 'node1',
           children: [
               { label: 'child1' },
               { label: 'child2' }
           ]
       },
       {
           label: 'node2',
           children: [
               { label: 'child3' }
           ]
       }
   ];
   ```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have the JavascriptSerializer object in .NET which can serialize most types

see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

and no you can't replace [ with { (obviously you can but almost all desrializers of JSON apart from something you wrote yourself wouldn't then understand the data)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Newtonsoft dll to serialize and deserialize JSON object. Please find details below.

http://james.newtonking.com/

http://json.codeplex.com/

To create JSON object you need to add Newtonsoft.Json dll and following code.

```
 string responseRGCDTO = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rgcDTO);
```